# Statistical distance for multiplicative blinding

Tags: blinding, statistical-distance

A common way to mask an integer $x$ in a range is to add a uniformly random integer $r$ from a much larger range. More formally, if $x$ lies in $[0,...,2^k)$ and $r$ in $[0,...,2^{k + l})$, then
$$\Delta(X+R,R) < 2^{-l}.$$

**Edit**: I mean multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$. If more specifically we're modelling a range $[-2^k,...,2^k)$ by mapping it into $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ for $n$ large enough to fit both ranges (and slightly more), then the sign of $x+r$ will agree with the sign of $x$, which can be useful.

In a similar setting, what is known about the statistical distance of $\Delta(X\cdot R,R)$? Again the requirement is that the sign of $x \cdot r$ agrees with that of $x$. Clearly $n$ would have to be much larger...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$, the statistical distance is always at least $\Omega(1/(k+l))$. A simple way to distinguish is to test whether the number is prime.

- The distribution $X\cdot R$ outputs a prime only when $1 \in \{X,R\}$, and this happens with probability at most $1/2^k + 1/2^{k+l}$.
- The distribution $R$ outputs a prime with probability $\Theta(1/(k+l))$ by the prime number theorem.

I don't know if this is a tight answer, but it's enough to show that multiplicative blinding is not very useful for cryptographic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicative blinding works much better in finite fields and rings.

Consider $GF(p),$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Then the map
$$
x\mapsto R\cdot x \pmod p
$$
is a permutation with no fixed points provided
$R \notin \{0,1\}.$ This directly gives
$$
\Delta(X,X\cdot R)=1/p
$$
which corresponds to a statistical distance not $2^{-k}$ but $2^{-(k+\ell)}$ (i.e., much lower) in your terminology.

If you avoid the divisors of the RSA modulus, this property survives. So if you let $N=pq,$ and choose $k$ from the set $[2,\ldots,p-1]$ (assume that $p<q$) you obtain the same statistical distance, i.e., $1/N$ otherwise you can obtain either $1/p$ or $1/q$ for $k$ divisible by $q$ or $p$ respectively, which is of the order $1/\sqrt{N}.$

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I actually meant to avoid overflows, and with that requirement this setup does not work. I was wondering if you have any more comments there...

Comment: can you clarify your comment about "overflow"?

Comment: Sorry! That was badly phrased. Thank you for pointing this out. I hope it is clearer now.